# Show that conditional variance of error in linear probability model is heteroskedastic?

Tags: econometrics, statistics, applied-econometrics, probability

I have a problem that asks me the following:

> " Consider the linear probability model, in which we specify the
> regression equation to be linear in X,
>
> E(Y |X = x) = Pr(Y = 1|X = x) = x'β
>
> We can accordingly express the regression equation by Y = X'β + e with
> E(e |X = x) = 0 for all x. Show that the conditional variance of e
> given X = x depends on x, i.e., e is heteroskedastic. "

Intuitively, I visualise why this is the case - but cannot figure out how to demonstrate this formally. Could someone help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be nice, however, to let us see what you visualize. What does heteroskedasticity mean?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgPhbVEbYqw

Comment: in my head i interpret it as: given that y's can only take two values - 1 and 0 - and the variance is the square of the distance between the actual observations and the regression line, when the the regression line is at y=0 - or to 1 -  then, for that precise X=x, there are many values that cancel out

Comment: @jamesstealth, did you watch the vid?

Comment: @EB3112: consider adding an answer here (based on the video you shared) so that the thread can be considered complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relation to the problem of heteroskedasticity in linear probability models, the following Ben Lambert video is a useful link:

youtube.com/watch?v=pgPhbVEbYqw